# Svn force export using c#

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, sharpsvn

I am trying to export files or folders from SVN using c#.
I used the SharpSvn lib.

```
SharpSvn.SvnClient svnclient = new SvnClient();
svnclient.Export(new SvnUriTarget(source), target, new SvnExportArgs());
```

I have been trying to export the source to directory.
It is successful(If folder doesn't exists)

But If the folder exists it throws the following error

*SharpSvn.SvnObstructedUpdateException: 'E:\abc\SVN\SVNtest' already exists*

In the command line,

```
svn --force export
```

will work

but for C#, what is the class or method I have to use to overwrite the existing folder.

I don't want to call any bat file or vbscript because I want to handle all the errors or exceptions in c# only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is a bit thin, but have you looked at the [`Overwrite` property](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/P_SharpSvn_SvnExportArgs_Overwrite.htm) of [`SVNExportArgs`](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/AllMembers_T_SharpSvn_SvnExportArgs.htm)?

```
SharpSvn.SvnClient svnclient = new SvnClient();
SvnExportArgs ex = new SvnExportArgs();
ex.Overwrite = true;
svnclient.Export(new SvnUriTarget(source), target, ex);
```

I haven't tested this, so I may be completely off the mark, but it *seems* logical.

Comment: Thank you. Except the 4th line everything works fine. :)

Comment: Sorry, doubled that up. Fixed now.